# How to disable adding real name to the from field when sending messages in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, privacy

When I email somebody (that is using whatever e-mail service of his own) using Gmail the recipient can see both my (the sender) e-mail address and real name like `Ivan Smith <ivan.smith@gmail.com>`. For a special reason I need to remove my name from the header and keep only declaring my e-mail address. Is this possible with Gmail (without using any extra e-mail client application)?

Answer (score 3):

In Gmail, go into Settings > Accounts and Import > Send mail as ... and change the name information under your default option to something else.

Comment: I would create a new email address and forward any incoming mail to your main account. If your address really is ivan.smith@ it won't take a rocketscientist to work out your name.